# How can I forward ALL pages to the same exact page on a different domain using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, forwarding

How can I do a **301 redirect** of ALL pages on a site to the same exact page on a different domain using **.htaccess**?

For example, forward:

```
www.currentdomain.com/page1.php    
www.currentdomain.com/page2.php?p=1&t=75       
www.currentdomain.com/archived/old/page100.php
```

To:

```
www.newdomain.com/page1.php    
www.newdomain.com/page2.php?p=1&t=75       
www.newdomain.com/archived/old/page100.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [about.com's article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/mod_rewrite/qt/site_redirects.htm), the following should redirect ALL traffic to a new domain:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your website add in the .htaccess file:

Redirect 301 /page1.php  www.newdomain.com/page1.php

Without mod_rewrite you can't transfer the parameters.  Further you have to have 1 line per existing file with .htaccess that you want to forward.

I know you didn't ask, but you can do the entire domain including the parameters with 1 line using mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do it in 1 line with mod_rewrite?