# htaccess rewrite all pages to same page on another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I've been looking but so far can;t find something that I'm looking for exactly. Looked at this article [How can I forward ALL pages to the same exact page on a different domain using .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168065/how-can-i-forward-all-pages-to-the-same-exact-page-on-a-different-domain-using) but it seems to only redirect my home page.

Currently, I'm using WordPress and I need to be able to forward all pages to a new domain. For example, domain1.com/about-us needs to go to domain2.com/about-us. But I have about 50 pages this needs to work on. I would like to see if there is a 1-5 line code to use for this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try putting this (above any wordpress rules) in the htaccess file in **domain1.com**'s document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If your 2 domains are one different webservers, or don't share a common document root, you can just use mod_alias, adding this to the htaccess file in **domain1.com**'s document root:

```
Redirect 301 / http://domain2.com/
```